# How to get the image digest by image name & tag

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to get the digest of a docker image which I have built and pushed to a private repository.
How can I get the digest by image-name:tag using a bash command?
I tried this command:

```
docker images --format "{{.Digest}}" --filter reference=${registry}/${image-name}:${tag}
```

but it doesn't return what I would like to get, e.g. just the digest of the `${registry}/${image-name}:${tag}` image.
Any help with this?

Comment: Have you tried `docker image ls --digests`?

Comment: I think this solved the issue: `docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' $IMAGE`

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue:

```
docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' $IMAGE
```